# Is this Kind of Makruh punished?

Tags: sin, makruh

Asssalmualaikum.

From my understanding, Makruh are the acts which are disliked.
And it is rewarded if one avoids it  and not punished if it is performed.
So is it still not punished, if one intentionally does it? Like ,knowing that it is makrooh, but still does the act.
Is this a sin?

Comment: What kind of makruh are you referring to?

Comment: You already answered your question: "not punished if it is performed"

Answer (score 1):

No what is makruh is frowned upon or disliked, but generally perfectly halal and certainly not sinful.

This means there's no punishment for doing something makruh at all.
Avoiding it is not rewarded, as it is not haram. Avoiding something haram on the opposite is rewarded.

Finally note that there's something called makruh tahrimi in the Hanafi maddhab (it doesn't seem to be a term used by earlier scholars) which is a bit different than the common definition of makruh.
See for example [According to Hanafi jurisprudence, marrying Jews or Christians is Makruh Tahrimi. Why is it Makruh Tahrimi even though it is allowed in the Qu'ran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39026/13438)